# is Camera calibration required if I change the height of the camera

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I use single-camera calibration with checkerboard and I used one fix position of the camera to do the calibration. Now my question is if I use the same position but change the height of the camera then do I need to do calibration again? If no then will I get the same result by using the different height of the camera?
In my case, I changed the height of the camera but the position of the camera was the same. And I got a different result when I changed height. So I was wondering that may I need to do again calibration of the camera or not?

please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "I got a different result"? Perhaps you can show images or whatever observations changes between the two cases?

Comment: in my case i use my camera for measuring distance between two horizotal line on the plane and my camera distance from the plane was 10meter. so i fixed my camera position and i made photo then i found out the distance between two horizontal line. lets say i got 10cm distance. after i changed the height of the camera but position was same, only chnage height from 1.33meter to 1.45meter. So i got distance between two horizontal line was 10.80cm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, and to achieve greatest accuracy, you will need to recalibrate the camera whenever it is moved. However, if the lens mount is rigid enough w.r.t the sensor, you may get away with only updating the extrinsic calibration, especially if your accuracy requirements are modest.

To see why this is the case notice that, unless you have a laboratory-grade rig holding and moving the camera, you can't just change the height only. With a standard tripod, for example, there will in general be a motion in all three axes amounting to a significant fraction of the sensor's size, which will be reflected in visible motion of several pixel with respect to the scene.

Things get worse / more complicated when you also add rotation to re-orient the field of view, since a mechanical mount will not, in general, rotate the camera around its optical center (i.e. the exit pupil of the lens), and therefore every rotation necessarily comes with an additional translation.

In your specific case, since you are only interested in measurements on a plane, and therefore can compute everything using homographies, refining the extrinsic calibration  amounts to just recomputing the world-to-image scale. This can easily be achieved by taking one or more images of objects of known size on the plane - a calibration checkerboard is just such an object.

Comment: I have one more question related to camera. I am using Sony ILCE-7RM2 camera with resolution  7952x5304 and my image size is 81.6MB. I would like to compress the size of an image but without loosing image quality and details of that image. I used MS Paint to resize the image. Is this better way to resize the image?

Comment: Do you want to resize the file or the image? Resizing the file (i.e. compressing the information in it) can be done without loss using several formats, for example LZ-compressed PNG.  Resizing the image (i.e. changing its width or height) generally implies loss of information.

Comment: Yes, I would like to resize an image.